# Canvas Arc Gradients

Tags: html, canvas, gradient

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193956/draw-arc-will-linear-gradient-html5-canvas) which is exactly the same question I have.

How can I apply a gradient to an arc like http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/ ?

Even if it was answered and the guy did approved the answer I still don't know what to do with the applyAngle function.

```
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(sx, sy, dx, dy);

gradient.addColorStop(0,   '#f00'); // red
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#ff0'); // yellow
gradient.addColorStop(1,   '#00f'); // blue

var applyAngle = function (point, angle, distance) {
    return {
          x : point.x + (Math.cos(angle) * distance),
          y : point.y + (Math.sin(angle) * distance)
    };
};
```

Anyone as a tiny working example how to apply this to a simple arc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223950/angle-gradient-in-canvas/22231473#22231473